# Store Interceptor and loose Value stack when redirection

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I have 2 actions. First to display form and another to process form. If `processAdd` action is not validated than redirectAction back to `Add` action. `Store` interceptor shows proper errors on the "Add" action but filled in values on the form are lost during redirect action.

I `loose Value Stack` on redirection, I understand that.

**Is there any solution to this?**

Don't want to use result param, too much work.

```
 <action name="add" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction" method="input">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/student.edit.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="processAdd" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">list</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">add</result>
            <result name="failure" type="redirectAction">add</result>
        </action>
```

Comment: @quaternion, I have tried but no success. Can you use my above code to explain how do you want me to do this?

Comment: See documentation, it explains that you can specify struts2 constants to allow for this, I think an explicit include parameter in a custom interceptor stack will make it work too: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ChainingInterceptor.html

Comment: i am not sure why to redirecting to another action on message failure? and why you want to do some much of work on validation failure.

Comment: @umesh-awasthi, I have my own reasons to do that. Sorry for the trouble. I could do that with session etc but wanted to know any auto support within the framework. Scope Interceptor is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Scope Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/scope-interceptor.html), not the Store Interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

[MessageStoreInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/message-store-interceptor.html)

> An interceptor to store a ValidationAware action's messages / errors
>   and field errors into HTTP Session, such that it will be retrieveable
>   at a later stage. This allows the action's message / errors and field
>   errors to be available longer that just the particular HTTP request.

You can't get the value stack data using message store interceptor it care's about action messages / errors and field errors.

Alternatively you can use *chain interceptor* or store values in session even message store interceptor uses session object to store message / errors.

Comment: Thanks. Already knew about it. Don't want to store errors from one action to another. I was interested in property values.