# Unable to repopulate values after xml validation in Struts2

Tags: validation, struts2

I was recently working with a login page with **Struts2** framework and for validating the fields i used ***XML Validation*** feature provided by **Struts2**.  And the fields are validated but the problem is that, if any of the field is not empty after validation the those field values are not repopulated in the corresponding field.The Example code is given.The version of the framework is 2.5.x.

**Login.jsp**

```xml
<s:form method="post" action="authenticate">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="input-icon"> 
                <s:textfield name="strUserName" id="strUserName" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username or Email"></s:textfield> 
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </span> 
                <span>
                    <s:fielderror fieldName="strUserName"/>
                </span>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <span class="input-icon"> 
                <s:password name="strPassword" id="strPassword" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password"></s:password> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
           </span> 
            <span>
                <s:fielderror fieldName="strPassword"/>
            </span>
        </div>
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />   
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",json"/>

    <!--    Set to false before deploying the application -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>

    <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="false" />
    <!-- constant to define global resource bundle -->
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="globalMessages" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />

<package name="<package_name>" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
<action name="authenticate" class="<Action_class_name>" method="<method_name>">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <result type="redirectAction">Successpage</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">login</result>
</action>   
<action name="login">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result>login.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**Action_name-validation.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
 <validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="fieldname">strUserName</param>
    <param name="trim">true</param>
    <message key="errors.required"></message>
 </validator>
  <validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="fieldname">strPassword</param>
    <param name="trim">true</param>
    <message key="errors.required"></message>
 </validator>
</validators>
```

**Action_name.java**

```
public class Action_name extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserModel> {
    private UserModel user;

    public String method_name() {
     if(success){
        return SUCCESS;
     }else{
       return INPUT;
     }
    }
    @Override
    public UserModel getModel() {
        user = new UserModel();
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Applicatin - intial run**

[image]

**Application - After Validation**

[image]

value "xyz" is not repopulated after the validation.

Comment: For security reasons you shouldn't repopulate that fields.

Comment: @RomanC its not working in not only in login form but other forms with same config.

Comment: That is why is not working but other forms are not related though.

Comment: I don't know why it is marked Duplicate.it does have a similarity but that's not what i have asked here.There is a type redirectAction is given in my code which is why the fields are not populated, which you wont find in the other question.So please read the question before you mark it duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate question is the one that is already asked before. You have asked the same question that was answered several years before, and your question can't be useful  to the community. You should know that SO is *not* Help and Support* site but Q&A. You should know [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the question before posting your problems here. Again, your problems already have been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. your login action

   ```xml
   <action name="login">
       <interceptor-ref name="store">
           <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <result>login.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```

   has only **a single** interceptor, the `MessageStore` one.

   It should have instead **at least** the `ModelDriven` and the `Parameters` Interceptors to work correctly. For example

   ```xml
   <action name="login">
       <interceptor-ref name="store">
           <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       <result>login.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```

   But note that this would lead to infinite recursion due to the `MessageStore` Interceptor always adding errors and the Workflow Interceptor always returning "input"; to avoid it you should define a secondary defaultStack in your struts.xml with all the intercpetors except the `Workflow` one, otherwise the `MessageStore` with `RETRIEVE` will make it loop or, if you haven't defined an input result for your login action,  complaining about a missing `input` result.
2. The second error is that you are redirecting, and hence losing the parameters. You're using the `MessageStore` Interceptor to preserve Action Messages, Action Errors and Field Errors across the redirection, but every other parameter is lost. If you want to preserve a parameter across a `redirectAction` you must explicitly send it, or store it in session in the source action and retrieving it in the destination action. In your case, it would be better to simply return the JSP in case of `input` result, instead of redirecting:

   ```xml
   <action name="authenticate" class="<Action_class_name>" method="<method_name>">
       <interceptor-ref name="store">
           <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       <result type="redirectAction">Successpage</result>
       <result name="input" >login.jsp</result>
   </action>
   <action name="login">
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       <result>login.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```

Comment: Adding the `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />` makes no change , still not repopulating.

Comment: The 2nd one Solved the issue, and thank you.But as you said how can i preserve the parameters across the action without removing redirectAction.

Comment: What do you know about Scope Interceptor?? i just heard i have no idea what it is. will that help to resolve this prob??

Comment: Never used the scope interceptor. The best shot is to remove redirectAction, otherwise you'd need to specify the parameters one by one, or [doing black magic like I've did here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685548/1654265), but seriously... do not try this at home :)

Comment: That's great. In Login form removing the redirectAction will resolve my prob. but there are other forms which have slimier issues where I must use the redirectAction as I have other processing in those action.Can you do some "Black Magic" here.:) . What do you get from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773877/store-interceptor-and-loose-value-stack-when-redirection

Comment: The point is that you should use PRG (Post Redirect Get) pattern, and performing redirect when needed. The INPUT result of an action that is asking you to logging in should be a dispatcher result of the same action, not the success result of another action.You redirect when you need to execute *another* action, for exmaple when you need to insert or update data, you execute the xxxinsert action, return redirectResult to xxxshow action, and in there you don't need to retain the previously inserted values, just to show the ones loaded from db. If in the xxxinsert action you get INPUT, you

Comment: return the jsp, not the xxxshow action. Then if you have data that must always be loaded (for example default comboboxes loaded from database), so that when you return a jsp from every action (show, insert, ecc) you have them always available, just put the loading in the prepare() method that is always executed. It's a nonsense to preserve unknown random parameters across redirections, you probably don't need those redirections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122556/discussion-between-zionz-and-andrea-ligios).